# git-svn branching without copying every subdirectory

Tags: git, git-svn

Our project's trunk looks something like:

```
trunk/foo
trunk/bar
trunk/baz
```

The subdirectories foo, bar, and baz are actually unrelated to each other, and bar and baz are actually quite huge. How do I create a branch with just foo, such that my branches would look something like:

```
branches/branch1/foo
branches/branch2/foo
```

Right now, what I'm doing is branching the whole trunk, then deleting bar and baz, but I think that would be problematic during the merge since it would try to delete bar and baz. What I'd like is for it to be intelligent enough to know that I just want to work with foo and not do anything with bar or baz.

Secondary question, not as important, what if I want a branch with foo and bar, like:

```
branches/branch1/foo
branches/branch1/bar
```

Would the process for branching these two folders without branching the others be harder?

Edit: 
It's been pointed out to me that I can use svn cp. This works, but I was hoping to work from a git svn repo, and as far as I can tell, the closest analogue git-svn has to svn cp is git svn branch, which automatically handles the copying. Unfortunately, I can't find any option in there that lets me branch just a specific subdirectory.

Answer (score 4):

It is common that one giant svn repository is represented by many git repositories. You should have used `git svn init .. -t trunk/foo -b branches/branch1/foo -b branches/branch1/foo` etc. Note: `init`, not `clone`. Then edit `.git/config`:

```
[svn-remote "foo"]
    url = http://server.org/svn
    fetch = trunk/foo:refs/remotes/foo/trunk
    branches = branches/*/foo:refs/remotes/foo/branches/*
    tags = tags/*/foo:refs/remotes/foo/tags/*
```

Then do `git svn fetch`. In addition you could specify `--ignore-paths` e.g., to ignore `docs` directory.

After that `git svn branch` should do the right thing. See [`git-svn manual`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this one a shot. I don't have a reference on me at the moment so lost on some of these details but it does sound like it might be what I wanted to do.

Comment: I'm a little confused by these flags: 
-b branches/branch1/foo -b branches/branch1/foo
I was under the impression that the -b flag was for specifying the parent folder where all the other branches go, but in this example it appears that we specify a -b for every branch we want to create?

Comment: I hope I'm not posting too much but I think this got me really really close to what I want. I get this message:
Copying https://x/trunk/foo at r2437 to https://x/branches/dev/branch1/foo...
... Which is exactly what I want. The only problem being that nothing actually happens. There is no branches/dev/branch1, and that's after waiting 10 minutes for "git svn branch -n branch1" to finish. That message is the only output.

Comment: @Miguel: if you edit the `.git/config` before doing `fetch` then you don't need to specify all branches with `-b`. Note: `branches/dev/branche1/foo` doesn't match the pattern `branches/*/foo`. The path patterns before `':'` in the `.git/config` should correspond to paths from your svn repo.

Answer (score 2):

svn copy will happily operate at any level in the folder structure.

Just do:

```
svn cp trunk/foo branches/branch1/foo
```

Think of it like a typical unix filesystem.

You might have to add --parents to the cp line if branch1 doesn't exist yet.

Comment: This will work on my SVN checkout, which I do have, but I'm having trouble finding a git-svn equivalent to this, and I was really hoping to work from the git svn repo instead.
My git-svn repo was checked out with "git-svn clone blahblah -t trunk -b branches", but I don't think there's a git-svn equivalent to svn cp, so I use git svn branch -n branchName, which copies all the directories over.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like git-svn is about being to use git on svn repo's. I haven't played with this, but I've been reading the man pages. Git-svn appears to be a method of having a local git style repository, but linked to an svn repo, instead of pushing to a git repo, which is a nice boost for someone wanting to use git for its distributed nature, but not have to switch the main repo to git to get it.

Comment: So, I'm thinking it's not a git-svn repo, it's just an svn repo, and your can use the cp command in the URL-OF-TARGET URL-OF-DESTINATION style to achieve your end.

Comment: @Miguel: I don't recommend using Git to manage Subversion branches. The branching model is different, and you'll probably hopelessly confuse both systems if you try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Branching in Subversion is basically just making copies of files (but they aren't *really* copies since they don't take up any space). So:

```
svn cp svn://server/repo/trunk/foo svn://server/repo/branches/branch1/foo
```

You don't need to copy the `bar` and `baz` directories if you don't want to. Alternately, you can copy everything (since copy is essentially free) and check out only what you need:

```
svn cp svn://server/repo/trunk svn://server/repo/branches/branch1
svn co svn://server/repo/branches/branch1/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure the exact syntax for this, nor do i know if this will work, but I think you could try to make the three different folders git submodules.

can you point the git clones to each trunk individually and clone them that way?

Comment: That might actually be a good idea. I'll give this a shot if Sebastian's solution doesn't work.